# How would you implement a CTA infront of a videoplayer?

Tags: customization, video-player

My goal is to place a call-to-action button in front of a YouTube video. Actually I'm placing this CTA above the video with an arrow between, but this looks ugly...

I want to make a button in front of the video - the CTA button should disappear after clicking - and the video must appear.

How would you achieve this the easiest way?

I'm not a fan of plugins and would like to find a very slim solution - thought something about javascript-onclick-overlay or maybe a slider - but I'm sure you have better ideas.